# Getting NU1202 error when running Nuget restore

Tags: .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a .NET Framework solution that I'm trying to set up with a pipeline on Azure DevOps. I'm getting an error when trying to restore packages though:

```
NU1202: Package AppCenter.Analytics.Metrics 1.1.0 is not compatible with net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0). Package AppCenter.Analytics.Metrics 1.1.0 supports: netstandard1.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.0)
```

And many more like this. It's right - that package isn't compatible with net40, but it shouldn't matter. There are several projects in the solution, but the oldest .NET version is 4.5, so I can't figure out where the v4.0 is coming from in the above. Other things that may be relevant:

1. The build output reports a NuGet version of 5.3.1.6268 and MSBuild version of 16.3.2.50909.
2. The solution restores and builds correctly locally.
3. I noticed a "v4.0" in the .sln.metaproj file: `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>`. That seems relevant, but I can't figure out where it's coming from or how to change it. Azure devops doesn't see this file as it's ignored by git, but I wonder what's causing that 4.0 there.

Here's a snippet from the pipeline.yaml:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release 2019'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '#####'
```

And here's one of the offending csproj files. There's some funny business for targeting multiple versions of Revit, and finding the location of Rhino dlls, but I can't see anything that would lead to trying to install packages for .NET v4.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Rhino7DefaultInstallDir>$([MSBuild]::GetRegistryValueFromView('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\McNeel\Rhinoceros\7.0\Install', 'Path', null, RegistryView.Registry64))</Rhino7DefaultInstallDir>
    <Rhino7DebugInstallDir>$([MSBuild]::GetRegistryValueFromView('HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\McNeel\Rhinoceros\7.0-WIP-Developer-Debug-trunk\Install', 'Path', null, RegistryView.Registry64))</Rhino7DebugInstallDir>
    <Rhino7InstallDir>$([MSBuild]::ValueOrDefault('$(Rhino7DebugInstallDir)', '$(Rhino7DefaultInstallDir)'))</Rhino7InstallDir>
    <Rhino7DefaultPluginsDir>$([MSBuild]::GetRegistryValueFromView('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\McNeel\Rhinoceros\7.0\Install', 'Default Plug-ins Folder', null, RegistryView.Registry64))</Rhino7DefaultPluginsDir>
    <Rhino7DebugPluginsDir>$([MSBuild]::GetRegistryValueFromView('HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\McNeel\Rhinoceros\7.0-WIP-Developer-Debug-trunk\Install', 'Default Plug-ins Folder', null, RegistryView.Registry64))</Rhino7DebugPluginsDir>
    <Rhino7PluginsDir>$([MSBuild]::ValueOrDefault('$(Rhino7DebugPluginsDir)', '$(Rhino7DefaultPluginsDir)'))</Rhino7PluginsDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="..\..\packages\Costura.Fody.3.3.3\build\Costura.Fody.props" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\Costura.Fody.3.3.3\build\Costura.Fody.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(Configuration.Contains('2018'))">
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <RevitVersion>2018</RevitVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(Configuration.Contains('2019'))">
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <RevitVersion>2019</RevitVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(Configuration.Contains('2020'))">
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <RevitVersion>2020</RevitVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Common ruleset shared by all projects -->
    <CodeAnalysisRuleset>$(SolutionDir)solution.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleset>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AdditionalFiles Include="$(SolutionDir)stylecop.json" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>9.0.30729</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{D6C256D4-B518-464F-9E68-CB282202E846}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Namespace</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>AssemblyName</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug 2018|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug 2018\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;REVIT_2018</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release 2018|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release 2018\</OutputPath>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DefineConstants>REVIT_2018</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug 2019|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug 2019\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;REVIT_2018; REVIT_2019</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release 2019|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release 2019\</OutputPath>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DefineConstants>REVIT_2018; REVIT_2019</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug 2020|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug 2020\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;REVIT_2018; REVIT_2019; REVIT_2020</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release 2020|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release 2020\</OutputPath>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DefineConstants>REVIT_2018; REVIT_2019; REVIT_2020</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualBasic" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\3.0\System.Management.Automation.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    ... Files ...
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
 ... More Files in ItemGroups ...
  <ItemGroup>
    ... Project References ...
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AppCenter.Analytics.Metrics">
      <Version>1.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics">
      <Version>2.6.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes">
      <Version>2.6.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers">
      <Version>2.9.8</Version>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="StyleCop.Analyzers">
      <Version>1.1.118</Version>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Choose>
    <When Condition="$(Configuration.Contains('Debug'))">
      <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="Eto">
          <HintPath>$(Rhino7InstallDir)Eto.dll</HintPath>
          <Private>False</Private>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Include="RhinoCommon">
          <HintPath>$(Rhino7InstallDir)RhinoCommon.dll</HintPath>
          <Private>False</Private>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Include="Rhino.UI">
          <HintPath>$(Rhino7InstallDir)Rhino.UI.dll</HintPath>
          <Private>False</Private>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Include="GH_IO">
          <HintPath>$(Rhino7PluginsDir)Grasshopper\GH_IO.dll</HintPath>
          <Private>False</Private>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Include="Grasshopper">
          <HintPath>$(Rhino7PluginsDir)Grasshopper\Grasshopper.dll</HintPath>
          <Private>False</Private>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Include="RevitAPI">
          <HintPath>C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit $(RevitVersion)\RevitAPI.dll</HintPath>
          <Private>False</Private>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Include="RevitAPIUI">
          <HintPath>C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit $(RevitVersion)\RevitAPIUI.dll</HintPath>
          <Private>False</Private>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Include="AdWindows">
          <HintPath>C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit $(RevitVersion)\AdWindows.dll</HintPath>
          <Private>False</Private>
        </Reference>
      </ItemGroup>
    </When>
    <Otherwise>
      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="RhinoCommon" Version="7.0.19274.12465-wip" IncludeAssets="compile; build" />
        <PackageReference Include="Grasshopper" Version="7.0.19274.12465-wip" IncludeAssets="compile; build" />
        <PackageReference Include="Revit_All_Main_Versions_API_x64" Version="$(RevitVersion).0.*" IncludeAssets="build; compile" />
      </ItemGroup>
    </Otherwise>
  </Choose>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ResolveAssemblyWarnOrErrorOnTargetArchitectureMismatch>None</ResolveAssemblyWarnOrErrorOnTargetArchitectureMismatch>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I haven't been able to figure out what to check for or how to debug this. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, which agent do you use, private agent or Microsoft hosted agent? Try excluding the `xx.sln.metaproj` and `xx.csproj.metaproj` from source control and run the pipeline again to check if the xx.metaproj caused this issue. If the issue persists, you may need to check the detailed log of nuget restore task(by setting system.debug=true) and check the project file of project that throws the NU1202. (Maybe it's multi-target?)

Comment: Hi friend, does this issue still block you? If there's any update, feel free to share here. I'll try my best to help:)

Comment: Sorry! I really appreciate the help. My testing time is limited today, but I'll give some of this a whirl this weekend and get back to you.

Comment: Hi friend, I've just updated my answer with the cause of your issue and possible workaround. Please check if it helps to resolve your issue, if it persists or you're confused with anything in my poor description, feel free to let me know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I noticed a "v4.0" in the .sln.metaproj file. I haven't been able to
>   figure out what to check for or how to debug this.

**Some tips that may help for trouble-shooting and resolving the issue:**

#1. I think the `.sln.metaproj` in solution folder and `.csproj.metaproj` in project folder should be excluded from Source Control. At least these files is not recommended to publish to `Azure Devops Repos`.

Check their content we can find something like `<ProjectConfiguration Project="{xxx}" AbsolutePath="C:\Users\xxx\source\repos\...>`, it's an absolute path in local machine. When using Hosted agent in Build Pipeline, these paths are invalid.

#2. Also, I checked the log of `Nuget Restore` task, and confirm the content of `xx.xx.metaproj` files won't affect the `nuget restore` process. So I think your issue didn't result from this.

#3 The NU1202 indicates the package is not compatible with current project. Check the log of `Nuget Restore` task you'll see something like this:

[image]

The error message will tell us which project causes the issue. Open the `xx.csproj` file in `Devops Repos` to check its content. I assume the version of the project targets v4.0 or one of its targetFrameworks([multi-targeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#how-to-specify-target-frameworks)) is v4.0. And if that project is a sdk-format project, you may need to use `dotnet restore` task to restore packages for that.

**Update:**

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-restore), `nuget restore` command won't receive and recognize build configuration. So for this situation, nuget can't access the propertyGroup whose conditions is `$(Configuration.Contains('xxx'))`. Then it is equivalent to `nuget restore xx.sln`=>nuget restore one project whose `TargetFrameworkVersion` is empty.And then nuget will consider this project uses default 4.0. So the issue occurs.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1.Create a simple .net framework 4.7 project, add this into `xx.csproj`:

```
    <PackageReference Include="AppCenter.Analytics.Metrics">
      <Version>1.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
```

2.Comment the `<!--<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7</TargetFrameworkVersion>-->`

3.Save all and `nuget restore xx.sln`, same issue occurs:

[image]

**Possible Workaround:**

`nuget restore` won't accept something like `nuget restore xx.sln -property:Configuration=xxx` like `nuget pack` command. So this issue will always occur unless we define the **valid** TargetFramework version in propertyGroup no matter which conditions. (I guess this is not what you want, but this issue cannot be avoided for this situation)

So I think a better choice is to use [`msbuild /t:restore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#restore-target) instead of `nuget restore`. For VS2017 and above, msbuild has contained the `restore` option itself. And it works for those `.net fx` based projects that use PackageReference format.

So you can use VS build task with arguments `/t:restore` to restore the packages instead of using Nuget restore(this is not suitable for your custom csproj script).

[image]

Comment: #1 Ah, so first clarification, the metaproj files weren't under source control, they're just one of the only places I found a "4.0" when searching through my project's files.
#3 I checked the log and there are a couple projects with that error. Both use multi-targeting, but none of the targets are to 4.0. I'll add one of the csproj files above.
I also tried using `dotnet restore` and received the same errors.

Comment: This is not about the restoring way. I do several tests and find this issue results from your empty targetframework version. I mean when you run the `nuget restore command`, nuget doesn't know the value of TFM, so it use the default 4.0 though it's not defined in csproj.

Comment: Ah, ok, that makes sense. Thanks for your help!