# Secret variable in Azure devops Pipeline in command line script does not get changed to stars *******

Tags: cmd, command-line, azure-devops, environment-variables, azure-pipelines

I am trying to sign some files in azure pipeline, I have added `.pfx` password as secret and trying to use it in `- script` command but for whatever reason it doesn't seem to get mapped.

[image]

Relevant section of script

```
 - script: 
      $(pathToSignTool) sign /f $(pathToPfx) /p %MAPPEDPASS% Some.vsto
  env:
    MAPPEDPASS: $(pfxPassword)
```

Output is

> Generating script.
> Script contents:
> C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Windows Kits"\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64\signtool.exe sign /f C:\DirWhereThePfxIs\key.pfx /p %MAPPEDPASS% Some.vsto

As I understand if mapping would work it would turn into **** rather than stay `%MAPPEDPASS%`

I have also tried `$(MAPPEDPASS)` and `$(env:MAPPEDPASS)` and `$MAPPEDPASS` without luck.

**How to map Secret variable in Azure devops Pipeline in command line script?**

EDIT: Added full yaml

```
# .NET Desktop
# Build and run tests for .NET Desktop or Windows classic desktop solutions.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/windows/dot-net

trigger:
- main

pool:
  name: 'XXX Build Pool'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  #change to actual directory where signtool is.
  pathToSignTool: "C:\\\"Program Files (x86)\"\\\"Windows Kits\"\\10\\bin\\10.0.19041.0\\x64\\signtool.exe" 
  #change to actual directory where .pfx is.
  pathToPfx: "C:\\DirWhereThePfxIs\\XXX.pfx" 

steps:
# commented out nuget as we have an issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59419416/ignore-nuget-package-restore-on-vdproj-projects-in-azure-pipelines
# but can't use workaround as currently no packages.config exist
#- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
#
#- task: NuGetCommand@2
#  inputs:
#    command: 'custom'
#    arguments: 'restore YourProjectName\packages.config -PackagesDirectory $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\packages'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- script: 
      $(pathToSignTool) sign /f $(pathToPfx) /p %MAPPEDPASS% XXX.vsto
  env:
    MAPPEDPASS: $(pfxPassword)
    # add actual password to variables (top right corner of this window) as it is 123456 now.

- script: 
      $(pathToSignTool) sign /f $(pathToPfx) /p %MAPPEDPASS% XXX.dll.manifest
  env:
    MAPPEDPASS: $(pfxPassword)

- script: 
      $(pathToSignTool) sign /f $(pathToPfx) /p %MAPPEDPASS% XXX.dll
  env:
    MAPPEDPASS: $(pfxPassword)
```

Comment: Can you show the full task?

Comment: @vernou Hi vernou. Done.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops), it seems that we have to do `$MY_ENV_VAR` to read a environment variable. In your case this done : `$(pathToSignTool) sign /f $(pathToPfx) /p $MAPPEDPASS Some.vsto`.

Comment: @vernou $MAPPEDPASS  also didn't fly.

Comment: As an aside, you don't double-quote each set of space separated subdirectories in a path, just double-quote it all, `"\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\bin\\10.0.19041.0\\x64\\signtool.exe\""`, which should resolve to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64\signtool.exe"`.

Comment: To expand… the resolved path shouldn't be, `C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Windows Kits"\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64\signtool.exe`, whilst Windows may be clever enough to ignore those double-quotes, because those are invalid characters in file and directory paths, they shouldn't be there, _even the still technically incorrect `C:\\\"Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\"\\10\\bin\\10.0.19041.0\\x64\\signtool.exe` would have been better, than what you had used!_

Comment: @Compo My apologies Compo :) thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is expected behavior to not have it changed to `******` but stay as `%MAPPEDPASS%`

[image]